# How to control slider speed in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my portfolio website. I have included a slider on my web page, I would like to know how i can control the slider and caption speed.

I had tried including this javaScript code to see if it works but no way.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$('.sl-slider').carousel({
    interval: 10000
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-item js-fullheight">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row d-md-flex no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-end" data-scrollax-parent="true">
            <div class="one-third order-md-last img js-fullheight" style="background-image:url(images/md_2.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="one-forth d-flex js-fullheight align-items-center ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '20%' }">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1 class="mb-4 mt-3"><span></span></h1>
                    <p></p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary px-5 py-3 mt-3">Get in touch</a></p>
                </div>
```

I expected the output to be a slide every 10 seconds, but it is still a slide every 3 seconds

Comment: What plugin are you using? This question doesn't include the necessary information.

Comment: I am using bootstrap.js

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You've provided stub code for both your JS and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using carousel in bootstrap. Try this:

```
<div id="yourCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"></div>
```